# Error CS0433: The type 'Encoding' exists in both (.Net Core 2.0)

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .Net Core app that builds and runs fine on Windows 10, but when I try building it on Ubuntu 16.04, the build fails on `CS0433: The type 'Encoding' exists in both 'System.Text.Encoding, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`.

I have tried `dotnet nuget locals --clear all` and deleting `~/.nuget` folder, but to no success. I've tried going through the detailed build output but I can't seem to find the part that goes horribly wrong.

[Here](https://paste.ee/p/0UEHM) is the detailed log output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.